# Stack Overflow private for teams does not offer preview of question

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, markdown

Question preview is a useful feature, but in the Stack Overflow for team (private), this **feature is disabled**.

[image: private]

The same markdown in the classic Stack Overflow (public), show the expected preview:

[image]

Comment: I never used Teams, but what happens when you toggle the "Markdown" switch in the top right corner?

Comment: I already used that button :( and preview does not appear

Comment: This is the new editor and it’s working as expected. Still, a lot of people liked the separate preview so adding that option back was requested somewhere in the answers to the original announcement: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/323179

Comment: why downvote?  Is a bad question? How can I improve it?

Comment: @JRichardsz - no, not necessarily, people may simply disagree this is a problem (or, more likely, because you did not check this is how the new editor works). That said, to second Laurel, I opted in for the new editor on Meta and after using it for a while, turned it off exactly for that reason - it is a ridiculous user experience to toggle preview all the time to see if the post looks just right.

Comment: Also, as your screenshot shows, it is extremely easy to make a mistake you are in the markdown version while you are actually in the "preview" version, and the post literally looks like "![image](link)"

Comment: I've seen previous reports where images from docs.oracle.com went belly up. Can you try with `https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZM07.png` which is your own image you posted here?

Comment: @rene that's possible, however, I am now pretty sure they are in the "wrong" mode, and the editor thinks they entered "hello ![image](..." as plaintext (judging by the switched off toggle). If that's true, this is a nice illustration why the new editors preview solution is a step backwards. JRichardsz - can you clear the post, switch on MD, paste the code back and confirm?

Comment: @OlegValter yeah, the editor is too smart for comfort. It needs to dumb down a bit.

Comment: I wonder if there should be some sort of guard against this... I [posted the thought](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362705) to the editor testing thread.

Comment: @zcoop98 - probably there should be (although I am not sure what this would mean from the technical standpoint - looking at MD token sequences?). Frankly, a toggle instead of switch would've been better here, I think the design team misunderstood the use case here.

Comment: You can edit in markdown and then toggle back to WISYWIG mode to see your preview

Answer (score 5):

You are unknowingly using [the new Stacks Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor#the-major-changes), which is currently distinct from the default one used on Stack Exchange sites. This editor does not provide a preview like the old editor does, and instead opts for two modes: Markdown mode, and rich text ([WSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG#:%7E:text=In%20computing%2C%20WYSIWYG%20(%2F%CB%88,web%20page%2C%20or%20slide%20presentation.))) mode.

In Markdown mode, you type plain text, optionally using Markdown syntax to add things like images and text stylings to your content. All content in Markdown mode will appear simply as styled plain text, and you will not see rendered content like images, tables, or quote blocks.

The rich text mode differs in that it renders a full "preview" of your content that you can edit. Unlike the old editor, which displays your preview *below* the input, [rich text mode displays the preview inline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor#preview-is-collapsed-into-the-rich-text-view), where you can edit it live, just like you would in a document editor.

To switch between these two modes, use [the Markdown switch on the upper right corner of the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor#the-markdown-rich-text-switcher), and make sure it's set to the "off" position with the grey color.

**The problem you're encountering** is that you have typed the *Markdown syntax* for an image into the *rich text* *mode* of the editor. Copy your image markup (`![image](...link here...)`), switch modes to Markdown, and paste it back into the editor.

To see your image rendered, switch the editor back to rich text mode.

Comment: In the public Stack Overflow, we have an option of opting-out of the alpha test; No such option is visibly available at the private teams, is it?

Comment: @EricWu I'm under the impression that the answer is "no," since the start of the [announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor) makes it sound like the Stacks Editor was launched fully on Teams last summer. Also worth noting that the new editor is opt-*in*, rather than opt-out, on MSE and MSO atm, meaning that only people that go looking for it will have it enabled.