# How do I opt-out of the new editor in private Stack Overflow Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Following up on this question: *[Stack Overflow private for teams does not offer preview of question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406335/stack-overflow-private-for-teams-does-not-offer-preview-of-question)*

The public Stack Overflow allows for *opting-in* the alpha test of the new editor at the [preferences page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/). Private teams have them enabled by default, and the users preference seems to have no effect on them.

Considering the alpha-state of the editor, and the fact that it is still being actively drawing feedback, (as per [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor)), *how do I opt-out of it in private teams?*

Comment: As far as I know, you can't op-out of using the new editor in Teams. The fact that you *must* use that editor in Teams is the primary reason for my almost nonexistent recent participation in the Teams I belong to, as I find *nearly every* contribution I make with that editor to be painful and frustrating. [Well, OK, my participation wouldn't be all that high without the new editor, but I do actively avoid creating content in Teams because of the editor.]

Comment: The fact that an alpha-staged feature is being _forced down_ in a paid system (granted, I'm not paying _yet_) is glaring PM flaw

Comment: I think it's worth noting that, even if you find the current bugs in the Stacks editor unbearable, you can more or less use it just like the old one if you leave it permanently in MD mode. Outside seeing a preview, I guess... and with some other quirks too ([eg.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360785)). ...Maybe that's not as great a solution as I first thought.

Comment: I sense this is coming to public Stack Overflow. The option to opt in or out is probably only until it's the default "feature".

Comment: @Scratte Via the [announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor#the-test), the end goal is definitely to replace the current editor, but before anyone panics, they've stated that it may take months or longer to finish testing, and longer still before a full-on roll out. To me, it sounds like they're prioritizing the right things, and really devoted to getting this right. I'm also not a Teams user that is forced to use the editor for every post, though, either.

Comment: @zcoop98 As far as I'm concerned, the only way they can "get this right" is by keeping the live preview, and I can't find anything in the announcement that says they're willing to consider that.

Comment: @zcoop98 - besides, a CM actively defended the decision to go with the toggle, so something tells me we will not be listened to in this case (sadly). I'd say it is time to panic :) The more we *publicly* panic, the better the chances are that things will be addressed (a common tactic of civil society getting what is needed from authorities not very keen on democratic processes so to speak).

Comment: @OlegValter I respect that; I also still feel like an alpha test is too early to panic, regardless of the context. If they've misused the term, then by all means, but if this is truly alpha test/ minimum-viable-product level of quality, then I'm not super worried.

Comment: @zcoop98 - I used the term "panic" a bit differently :) Alpha test or not, I think the more vocal we are about the shortcomings, the better (we even have an example of the success of the tactic when SE tried to roll out the "thank you" feature. Cookie popup problem is now actively being looked into as well). That said, I don't have the trust in SE to go back on design choices once they make their mind, and the responses to the highest voted posts (several of which ask for the live preview to be reinstated) on the announcement page seem to confirm that. Hope to be proven wrong though.

Comment: @OlegValter I understand you better now! What you've said makes a ton of sense. Being vocal is probably even more beneficial in this case, where SE is directly and actively soliciting feedback on a feature. Being as vocal as possible about issues, in theory, leads to users being more likely to have their grievances addressed, and SE being more likely to have a larger number of issues cleared up by release time. That's definitely a win-win. I also agree that SE seems largely reluctant to back out of past design choices... This makes present feedback that much more important.