# Why are we unable to disable the new Markdown editor in Private Teams?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams, markdown

In relation to a question I rose [8 months ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406783/how-do-i-opt-out-of-the-new-editor-in-private-stack-overflow-teams), and a similar one
@Brad Mace rose [5 months ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409045/disabling-new-editor-in-our-teams-site).

The feature is in an alpha state and an option to disable it exists in the public Stack Exchange communities.

Why, given it's *alpha state*, is it being forced down in a *paid* platform? What are the motivations for that?

Comment: Your question is an exact duplicate. This isn't a "discussion" you're asking "how" which makes it a support question and the answer is "you can't" - which is what is said in the answer to Brad's question. If you want to actually have a discussion, then you'll need a different question but repeating the same question isn't going to do anything. Essentially, you edited the wrong part of the post - edit the title.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @Catija. I understood the feedback now. In this case, what would be a proper title, in order to invite the discussion?

Comment: I'm under the impression (might be wrong in that) that "Why is this feature being forced down our throats" would be too contentious for this forum :)

Comment: There are nice ways of asking that question, though - you don't have to be confrontational about it. I'm in the same position you are. I never use the rich text mode, which means I just never see a preview of my posts before they go up - or I compose my posts on a public site and then paste them into a Team. I know there's a ton of work we want to do to improve it but I have no clue what the priority is to do so. I don't have any insight into the feedback the Teams product team gets about it to know whether it's generally considered a good editor by the customers or not.

Comment: The fact that the linked duplicates don't have a work around doesn't make them not duplicates. There's a reason there is no work around; because the isn't one. If you are using Teams you have to s̶u̶f̶f̶e̶r use the alpha editor.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no option other than the "new editor" on Teams. Stack Overflow has decided it's the only thing available for their paid/free Teams product, despite consistent, substantial feedback that it has major problems. That SO has chosen this, and chosen not to address the issue for substantially more than a year, is a factor you should consider when choosing to use/pay for the service (as is normal for paying for anything). My choice has been to use Teams as little as possible, including the ones where I'm a member for free, and recommend against the product to others.

Comment: @Makyen That is ... obnoxious. I absolutely love MSE, SO, and others, and I've been looking forever for a reason to actually promote their products where I work. The fact that they believe such a move would not hurt their reputation is, for the lack of another term, amateurish.

Comment: @EricWu Equally amateurish would be having a product targeted at businesses that *only* supports markdown. While markdown might be prevalent in the programming/tech world, it's relatively uncommon outside of it. (that of course doesn't excuse forcing teams into using an alpha editor that doesn't appear to be getting worked on)

Comment: Any product team is going to respond to customer demand when growing and improving their products. That's why the editor was built - many of the people using Teams don't know MD at all, so they needed a rich text editor that would be more similar to what they're used to - and (more importantly) could accept pasted content from existing docs without losing formatting. Similarly, new product work focuses on the big asks from customers - if there's not a huge outcry amongst users about the editor, or if other asks are seen as higher priority (new features, etc), it's not going to get built.

Comment: Though I understand that many users don't understand MD that use Teams @Catija , there's also many users that do, and have been using Stack Overflow for years. I'm not against improving the editor (it annoys me it still uses code blocks, not code fences for example), but the Rich Text editor isn't "fun" for those of us that want to use MD, and the lack of a preview feature is... Well, it makes the MD editor somewhat useless (in my opinion).

Comment: @EricWu As Catija mentioned, something like this is, ultimately, a business decision. SE recognized that the editor they use for their main sites didn't fill the needs of the customers they were trying to target with their Teams product, so they created the "new editor" to resolve that. That's good and appropriate, assuming the new editor meets the needs they were targeting. It is, however, unfortunate that SE chose to not to give those of us who find the new editor a **very** negative experience the option of using the original editor, as not having the option alienates that customer segment.

Comment: @Makyen, being a business discussion, is this the wrong place to discuss about it? I was under the impression that MSO was to be the place where feedbacks were to be collected regarding Private SO.

Comment: @EricWu this is the only place to discuss it publicly on the SE network. One could always reach out to product support